# Magento 2 Error Argument #4 ($...) must be of type

Tags: magento2

I want to add a column for the customer-agent =>(my module) in order table
I add this in to app/code/Orienteed/CustomerAgent/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="add" class="Orienteed\CustomerAgent\Ui\Order\AddButton" />
        </buttons>
    </settings>
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="customer_agent" class="Orienteed\CustomerAgent\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomerAgent">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Agent</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="customerRepositoryInterface" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface</argument> 
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

and creating app/code/Orienteed/CustomerAgent/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/CustomerAgent.php

```
<?php

namespace Orienteed\CustomerAgent\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;

class CustomerAgent extends Column
{
    protected $orderRepository;

    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $customerRepositoryInterface;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                $orderId = $item['entity_id'];
                $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
                $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
                $customer = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
                var_dump('getCustomerIdgetCustomerId',$customer,'getCustomerId') ;
                if ($customer) {
                    $customerAgent = $customer->getData('customer_agent')->getRoleName();
                    $item[$this->getData('name')] = $customerAgent;
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

but I qot this error
`Type Error occurred when creating object: Orienteed\CustomerAgent\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomerAgent, Orienteed\CustomerAgent\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomerAgent::__construct(): Argument #4 ($customerRepositoryInterface) must be of type Orienteed\CustomerAgent\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface, Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor given, called in /app/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` from you website root.